# Is there a way to invalidate metadata and rebuild index from python code in CDSW?

Tags: python, cloudera, impala, impyla

I am using Impyla and Python in the CDSW to query data in HDFS and use it.  The problem is sometimes to get all of the data I have to go in and manually click on the "Invalidate all metadata and rebuild index" button in HUE.

Is there a way to do this in the workbench with a library or python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using something like this to connect to `impala` via `impyla` ... try executing the `invalidate metadata <table_name>` command

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='my.host.com', port=21050)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('INVALIDATE METADATA mytable') # run this
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100')
print cursor.description  # prints the result set's schema
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  I knew that there was an 'INVALIDATE METADATA' command but I thought you could only use it from the command line.  Thank you very much @thePurplePython